# How to split variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

If I have a variable

```
var number = 123
```

how can I split it into an array like this?

```
[0]=1
[1]=2
[2]=3
```

I know there is a string split but what about variables?

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you know how to convert a number to its String representation?

Comment: Use division and subtraction

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your number to a `string`, then use `split()` on it, then map it back to numbers like this:

```
var num = 123; // 123
var str = num.toString(); // "123"
var arr = str.split(''); // ["1", "2", "3"]
var numberArr = arr.map(Number); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I ran all three answers on jsPerf. This is the fastest!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get *really* cheeky you can do this, since strings are indexed in an array-like fashion.

```
function splitNum(num) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(num.toString(), Number);
}

var num = splitNum(555); // >> [5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 123;
var temp;

number = number.toString();

for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
{
    temp = number[i];
    number[i] = number[number.length - 1 - i];
    number[number.length - 1 - i] = temp;
}

console.log(number[0]);
console.log(number[1]);
console.log(number[2]);
```